# How to show that $\mathbb{C} ((z))((w))$ is a field

Tags: abstract-algebra, power-series, formal-power-series

Notation: with $\mathbb{C} ((z))((w))$ we denote the space of formal bilateral power series which have bounded below powers of $w$ but not uniformly bounded below powers of $z$ (this is in the context of vertex algebras, which I am reading about [here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Efrenkel/loop.pdf), section 2.2.3). For example
$$\sum_{n \leq 0} z^{n} w^{n} $$
doesn't belong to $\mathbb{C} ((z))((w))$, while
$$\sum_{n \geq 0} z^n w^{n}$$
or
$$\sum_{\substack{n \geq -m \\ m\geq -4}} z^n w^{m}$$
do belong to this space. Note that in the last example the power of $w$ is bounded from below, while the same is true for the power of $z$ only when $m$ is fixed and we consider the coefficient of $w^m$.

Now the point of the question: I'm trying to show that $\mathbb{C} ((z))((w))$ is a field, but this is not clear at all to me. I guess I have to formally expand something in order to find a somewhat explicit expression for $1/f$ where $f\in \mathbb{C} ((z))((w))$ is a generic element.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Given any field $K$, you can show $K((w))$ is a field.

Comment: Of course, I didn't think about that. Thanks.